# Probability of a 2 Period in a Random Function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Source**: Similar to problem 3.1.11 in Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*. Here, let $[m]=\{ 1,2,\dots,m \}$ denote the set of the first $m$ natural numbers.

> Suppose we pick a function $f: [m]\rightarrow [m]$ uniformly from the $m^m$ possibilities and a starting point $x_0$ uniformly from the set $[m]$. We are interested in the sequence of compositions
> $$ x_0,f(x_0),f(f(x_0)),f^3(x_0),\dots $$
> What is the probability that our sequence ultimately fluctuates between two values (i.e. reaches a period of 2)?

**Work**: I'll try counting. We can start by choosing the number of 2 periods in our function - this ranges from 1 to $\lfloor m/2\rfloor$. For a given $i\leq \lfloor m/2\rfloor$, there are

$$\binom{m}{2}\binom{m-2}{2}\cdots\binom{m-2i+1}{2}$$

ways of selecting $i$ 2 periods (i.e. $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$). There are $m-2i$ inputs left from this to delegate an output. Suppose $j$ of these $m-2i$ inputs do not form a 2 period nor lead to a 2 period previously created - there are $j^j - \binom{j}{2}$ ways for this to occur. The remaining $m-2i-j$ can be mapped to any of the values that eventually reach a period - there are $(m-2i-j)!/(2i-1)!$ ways of doing so. Lastly, there is a $(m-j)/m$ chance of choosing a favorable starting point. Thus, I get the probability as

$$ \left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-2i}   (m-j)\left(j^j - \binom{j}{2}\right)\frac{(m-2i-j)!}{(2i-1)!} \prod\limits_{k=0}^{i-1} \binom{m-2k}{2}\right] \bigg/ m^{m+1}. $$

**Question**: This looks very messy (and obviously wrong). It seems I forgot how to count and hope someone could help me out. A simple non-counting argument would also be interesting to me - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too unwieldy to count the functions leading to a period of $2$ in the manner you describe. Here is a different method which yields a tidy summation for an answer.

Call the entries of this sequence $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$. So, $x_1=f(x_0)$, $x_2=f(f(x_0))$, etc.

Imagine the elements of the list $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$
were revealed to you one by one. Since the underlying function $f$ is random, and unknown to you, this will apparently be a partially random sequence. This sequence has the following two properties. When you are observing $x_i$ for the first time $(i\ge 0)$,

1. If there exists $j$ such that $0\le j\le i-2$ and $x_{i-1}=x_{j}$, then it is always true that $x_{i}=x_{j+1}$.
2. Otherwise, $x_i$ is chosen uniformly at random from $[m]$.

In order to reach a period of $2$, if $i$ is the index of the first repeated value in the random sequence $(x_0,x_1,\dots)$, then it must be true that $x_{i-2}=x_i$. Conditional $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}$ being pairwise distinct, the probability that $x_{i-2}=x_i$ is equal to $1/m$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{period }=2)
&=\sum_{i=2}^{m}P(x_0,\dots,x_{i-1}\text{ distinct})P(x_i=x_{i-2}\mid x_0,\dots,x_{i-1}\text{ distinct})
\\&=\sum_{i=2}^m \frac{m^{\underline i}}{m^i} \cdot \frac1m.
\end{align}
$$
As a fun fact, using the fact that $m^{(i)}/m^i$ is approximately equal to $\exp(-i^2/2m)$ provided $m$ is large enough, you can prove that this probability is asymptotically equivalent to $$\sum_{i=2}^m \frac{m^{\underline i}}{m^i} \cdot \frac1m\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2m}} \qquad \text{as $m\to\infty$}.$$

Comment: I just realized Knuth gave this exact probability as well in the back of the book. I think by $P(x_0,\dots ,x_{i-1} \text{distinct})$, you mean the product of $(1-\frac{0}{m})\cdots (1-\frac{i-1}{m})$. I was confused by the notation or rendering of that second line in the first align mode. Anyhow thanks!

Comment: Silly I didn't realize the relation to the Birthday problem